# Simple inheritance with functions in subclasses

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, inheritance

It seems like there are many ways implementing inheritance in JavaScript. Which version do you prefer or would you suggest another solution?

The code should run in IE8+ so my first version would not fit…

```
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name
}
Animal.prototype = {
    eat: function() {
        console.log(this.name + ': *eat*')
    }
}

function Cat(name) {
    Animal.call(this, name);
}
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype, {
    miaou: {
        value: function() {
            console.log(this.name + ': *miaou*')
        }
    }
})

var garfield = new Cat("Garfield");
garfield.eat();     // Garfield: *eat*
garfield.miaou();   // Garfield: *miaou*


// ------------
//
// possible alternative:

// […] see http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ for definition
// of Class

var Animal2 = Class.extend({
    init: function(name) {
        this.name = name
    },
    eat: function() {
        console.log(this.name + ': *eat*')
    }
});

var Cat2 = Animal2.extend({
    init: function(name) {
        this._super(name)
    },
    miaou: function() {
        console.log(this.name + ': *miaou*')
    }
});

var garfield2 = new Cat("Garfield2");
garfield2.eat();        // Garfield: *eat*
garfield2.miaou();      // Garfield: *miaou*
```

Comment: It looks like you're looking for opinions as to which to use, and not a code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joseph mentioned, opinion questions is not what CodeReview is about.

I tend to review every OO approach with these 4 questions:

**Approach 1**

- Does *instanceof* still work ? -> Yes, good
- Do you introduce new properties, causing potential naming clashes -> No, good
- Can parameters easily be provided to the constructors -> Yes, good
- Can I easily have properties in .prototype -> Yes, good

**Approach 2**

- Does *instanceof* still work ? -> Yes, good
- Do you introduce new properties, causing potential naming clashes -> Yes, not so good
- Can parameters easily be provided to the constructors -> Yes, good
- Can I easily have properties in .prototype -> Yes, good

The second approach uses `_super`, which is not perfect but definitely acceptable, and the framework was written by John Resig..

In the end, you should use the right tool for the job, and since you provided example code, we can't really tell you which approach is best.